# Mix DirectX 12 and XAML controls in UWP

Tags: uwp, c++-cx, uwp-xaml, directx-12

I would like to create a UWP app (XAML) with C++/CX and DirectX 12 so that I can mix both XAML controls (things like Grid, buttons...) and DirectX, something like a Level Editor, but I'm struggling to find a way how to initialize DirectX to render inside a specific control (like a Grid).

The basic template and all the other tutorials only show how to do it within the full area of the application. When creating a device resource we set the window where to draw with SetWindow(CoreWindow::GetForCurrentThread());

Is there a way how to create a device resource with hwnd from a xaml control and is there a way how to get hwnd for a specific control?

Comment: *"is there a way how to get hwnd for a specific control?"* - No. XAML controls aren't backed by individual native windows, which `HWND` references. There's just a single `HWND` for the application window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The information in the article [DirectX - Using XAML with DirectX and C++ in Windows Store Apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991975.aspx) all applies to mixing Direct3D 11 or Direct3D 12 with XAML.

> It's not clear why you'd want to write your level editor with DirectX 12. In general DirectX 11 is a much easier-to-use API. Unless you are already hitting the CPU-side performance limits of DirectX 11, it's probably more work than it's worth for a level editor.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! 
The reason why Dx12 and not 11 is really simple - just wanted to learn something new :) But I get your point about DirectX 11, it makes perfect sense for some production ready product. And it is not the Level Editor app that I am trying to do, it is more for testing different approaches for big maps and different techniques on generating them, therefore I would need an easy way on how to change or add parameters, display some results and logs...

Answer (score 0):

For further reference, here is an official code example: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsappdev/2012/03/15/combining-xaml-and-directx/

Comment: That link is specific to Windows 8. While helpful in understanding, what's going on inside, most of this is has changed with UWP (i.e. Windows 10). See [DirectX and XAML interop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/directx-and-xaml-interop) for details.

Comment: Yep, that one is up to date. Thanks for sharing!