# Porting Directx12 Asset into XAML element: advice on WRL::ComPtr replacement?

Tags: c#, c++, wpf, clr, directx-12

I'm working on creating a WPF asset (like [D3D11Image](https://github.com/Microsoft/WPFDXInterop)), from a DirectX12 Win32 desktop sample : [D3D12PipelineStateCache](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectX-Graphics-Samples/tree/master/Samples/Desktop/D3D12PipelineStateCache), so I can embedd it as **XAML element in a WPF application**.

Microsoft Directx12 samples are having extensive usage of `ComPtr` (`using Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr;` and `#include <wrl.h>`), smart pointers, but build fails because of:

```
// Don't allow to compile sources with /clr
#ifdef _MANAGED
#error WRL cannot be compiled with /clr option enabled
#endif
```

Repro: I started to change configuration properties in the D3D12PipelineStateCache project:

- configuration type: Dynamic Library
- clr support: /clr
- .net target: v4.5

The goal was to "detach stop by stop the code from win32" and make it interfaced with XAML assets.

Do you have any recommendation of smart pointer to replace `ComPtr` or do you recommend to proceed differently, eg., by building a pure c++ dll with interop with clr dll, and in that case, how ?

Comment: this answer is for a UWP project, think might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39683147/366064

Comment: You are looking at the wrong samples.  Easy mistake, there are rather a lot of them that show how to use DirectX in a UWP app and they are all fresh.  The ones that demonstrate it in a desktop app are much older and not as well published.  Lots to choose from, consider CComPtr.

Comment: @HansPassant `CComPtr` won't fit since it doesn't have `get()` method to get the address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WRL generally assumes you will be using the Windows Runtime which is explicitly designed to interop with C# and C++, so the Managed C++ (`/clr`)) scenario is exclude.

You should be able to use ATL's `CComPtr` instead by including `<atlbase.h>`, but it will take some code changes to work.

- Keep in mind is that `operator&` in the older ATL `CComPtr` asserts that the pointer is always null before doing the equivalent of `GetAddressOf`. In `ComPtr` the use of `operator&` explicitly calls the equivalent of `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf` to release any existing pointer to avoid potential memory leaks.
- There's no `Get`, `GetAddressOf`, or `ReleaseAndGetAddressOf` method as `CComPtr` uses the old-school automatic conversion to a raw pointer which is [problematic](https://herbsutter.com/2012/06/21/reader-qa-why-dont-modern-smart-pointers-implicitly-convert-to/)
- There is no `Reset` method for clearing `CComPtr` so you have to set it to `NULL`.
- There is no `As` method so you have to use the more wordy `QueryInterface` solution.

You can probably work around most of these issues by deriving a helper version that adds the missing methods but it will take a bit of work...

```
struct MyComPtr : public ATL::CComPtr
```