Can Direct3D 12 render to Xaml.Media.Imaging.SurfaceImageSource?
Here is the tutorial I am using.
Chuck has said twice that this is possible
https://stackoverflow.com/a/39683147/11998382
However, ISurfaceImageSourceNative::SetDevice accepts a IDXGIDevice which is a Direct3D 11 legacy thing that is no longer supported with Direct3D 12. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40427079/11998382
The docs for ISurfaceImageSourceNative::SetDevice clearly indicate that it is a Direct3D 11 owned resource.

Sets the DXGI device, created with D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT, that will draw the surface. This method must be called from the UI thread.

What did Chuck mean by his answers? Does this require interop between 11 and 12? I don't even think 12 can render to a 11 owned texture. ChatGPT thought it was possible with shared handles.
I'm going to try to with ID3D11On12Device tomorrow.

Windows.UI.Xaml.dll is totally bound to DirectD311 (and WPF is still totally bound to DirectX9). IMHO, Chuck's answer is unrelated to ISurfaceImageSourceNative specifics and Windows.UI.Xaml, it's a general fact about DirectX. You absolutely need a DXGI device in your case (same as for WinUI BTW), I think D3D11on12 should work since it can get you a IDXGIDevice, but not tested. PS: D3D11 is not legacy

@SimonMourier yes he probably meant using a SwapChainPanel

It works fine with ID3D11On12Device.
auto width_height = std::array{ 300U, 300U };
auto surfaceImageSource = winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml::Media::Imaging::SurfaceImageSource(width_height[0], width_height[1]);
auto m_sisNative = surfaceImageSource.as<ISurfaceImageSourceNative>();

winrt::check_hresult(m_sisNative->SetDevice(resources.dxgiDevice.get()));

winrt::com_ptr<IDXGISurface> surface;

POINT offset{};
RECT updateRect{0, 0, width_height[0], width_height[1]};
winrt::check_hresult(m_sisNative->BeginDraw(updateRect, surface.put(), &offset));

auto d3d11 = surface.as<ID3D11Resource>();
auto pResource = d3d11.get();
resources.m_d3d11On12Device->AcquireWrappedResources(&pResource, 1);

Chuck linked to the same tutorial which has a section on interop with both SurfaceImageSource and SwapChainPanel.
He was obviously meaning DX12 can render using SwapChainPanel. DX12, however, cannot render with SurfaceImageSource.
